# Selenium click()

Tags: python, selenium

"""
Web scraping the wikipidia page
"""

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")

num_articles1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#articlecount a')
print(num_articles1.text)

num_articles1.click()


driver.close()
```

Question: num_articles1 returns the value but why is the click() not working ?
can't understand why is this happening, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

On my *Windows 10* using latest *Selenium*, *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome* the number of articles i.e. *`6,559,615`* gets printed perfectly and the *`click()`* is also performed perfecto.

---

However, to click on the ***clickable*** element ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#articlecount a"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='articlecount']/a"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Yeah, it is a working code, just need to add a while loop to keep it working using the date time module